# OpenEJB - configuring datasource for JUnit

Tags: jakarta-ee, persistence, openejb

I have problem with proper configuration of datasource for OpenEJB 3.1.3. I try to configure connection to postgres db, but hen I debug test I get default hsql connection parameters.

Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(ApplicationComposer.class)
public class OpenEJBTest {
    @EJB
    Files fb;

    @Test
    public void testSth() {
        List<UploadSession> uploadNotFinishedSessions = fb.getUploadNotFinishedSessions();
    }

    @Module
    public EjbJar beans() {
        EjbJar ejbJar = new EjbJar("beans");
        ejbJar.addEnterpriseBean(new StatelessBean(FilesBean.class));
        ejbJar.addEnterpriseBean(new StatelessBean(FilesUtilBean.class));
        ejbJar.addEnterpriseBean(new StatelessBean(ServerFilesBean.class));
        ejbJar.addEnterpriseBean(new StatelessBean(UserUtilBean.class));
        return ejbJar;
    }

    @Module
    public PersistenceUnit persistence() {
        PersistenceUnit unit = new PersistenceUnit("postgresPU", HibernatePersistence.class.getName());
        String simpleXml = SimpleXmlUtil.toSimpleXml(unit);
        System.out.println(simpleXml);
        unit.setJtaDataSource("PostgresDS");
        unit.setNonJtaDataSource("PostgresDSUnmanaged");
        return unit;
    }
}
```

I tried to:

1. add jndi.properties to classpath:

> ```
> postgresPU=new://Resource?type=DataSource
> postgresPU.JdbcDriver=org.postgresql.Driver
> postgresPU.JdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql:/localhost:5433/pdb
> postgresPU.JtaManaged=true
> postgresPU.DefaultAutoCommit=false
> postgresPU.UserName=...
> ```

1. Configure datasources via openejb.xml (located on classpath)

> ```
> <Resource id="PostgresDS" type="DataSource">
>   JdbcDriver  org.postgresql.Driver
>   JdbcUrl   jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/pdb
>   UserName   user
>   Password  pass
>   JtaManaged true
> </Resource>
>
>  <Resource id="PostgresDSUnmanaged" type="DataSource">
>      JdbcDriver  org.postgresql.Driver
>     JdbcUrl     jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/pdb
>      UserName    user
>     Password    pass
>   JtaManaged  false
>  </Resource>
> ```

But neither of it works - datasources are not being configured at all, the default version  of datasource remains.
Because of default hsql connection I get following bug:

```
WARN - SQL Error: -22, SQLState: S0002
ERROR - Table not found in statement [select top ? user0_.id as col_0_0_ from tusers user0_ where user0_.login=?]
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ApplicationComposer` doesn't use JNDI to bootstrap the container so the `jndi.properties` file is never seen.

What you can do instead is use the `org.apache.openejb.junit.Configuration` annotation on a method to have it return the properties you want to use to configure the test.

```
@Configuration
public Properties properties() {
   //...
}
```

I'd rename `jndi.properties` to something else so it isn't confusing, then you can use code like this to find it in the classpath.

```
   final URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/config.properties");
   final Properties props = new Properties();
   final InputStream in = url.openStream();
   try {
       props.load(in);
   } finally {
       close(in);
   }
```